# My service task dies with no reason

Tags: c#, .net, service, task-parallel-library

I have a task in windows service. Heres the code of interest:

```
private Task Schedule(Action action, int interval, EventDefinition restoreEvent = null) {
    return new Task(() => {
        bool error = false;
        while (IsEnabled && !CTS.Token.IsCancellationRequested) {
            if (!IsPaused) {
                try { // we don't want our service to crash if anything goes wrong on production
                    action();
                    if (error && restoreEvent != null) SysEvent(restoreEvent);
                    error = false;
                }
                catch (Exception x) {
                    error = true;
                    SysEvent(new EventDefinition { Id = x.HResult, Message = x.Message, Type = EventLogEntryType.Error });
                }
            }
            CTS.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(interval);
        }
    }, CTS.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

As you can see - my service task runs in loop, endless loop, the loop could end only when IsEnabled is set to false, and this is set in only 2 points: service start and service stop code. It can also end when task cancellation is requested, but this stops the service.

But my service is running! It haven't received any stop or cancellation request. No exception could break the task in while loop. But after about 30 hours - the service just stopped to do it's job with no reason. Its state is still running. THERE IS NO SINGLE ERROR OR WARNING IN ANY SYSTEM LOG! It just died silently.

What has happened? Any clues? Can .NET task just die like this?

Comment: I think it can die like that if the service has nothing to do...

Comment: What .NET version? Starting a task only to run a loop inside it is a horrible misuse of Tasks. Why not use a single thread then? And is CTS.Token the global variable I think it is?

Comment: BTW tasks should be short-lived and NOT block just to cause a delay. This wastes a valuable thread. You can use the Task.Delay method to delay execution until a later time

Comment: Yes, I start it with Task.Start() - is it wrong?

Comment: .NET 4.5, why the loop is a misuse? It waits quietly for specified interval using no resources. I need to do my action every t milliseconds. I could use timer, but why the task is wrong here? The code with the timer was longer and less readable.

Comment: CTS is global for all tasks - if I stop the service, I need to cancel all tasks. BTW, Task.Delay does not delay specific task. It creates new task which does nothing and completes after specified interval. How should I use it here?

Comment: Sure it could crash. If your call to `SysEvent` in the exception handler throws an exception, the thing will die a horrible death. It could also crash on the `CTS.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne` if for some reason the token or wait handle were disposed or set to null. And, of course, something could be setting the cancellation flag unexpectedly. Or something might have set the paused flag. Hard to tell what's going on with all those globals you have in there.

Comment: Thank you all - I've ended this awful tasks misuse and created a new, better class ServiceTask using System.Threading.Timer. Works as charm so far, no while loops ;) If it dies - there MUST be a trace in Event Log. But so far so good. BTW, it uses less memory than the version with tasks.